# Ouput value from sentinel loop is wrong

Tags: java

I have written an tax program, where I input certain values in and it prints the output at the very end of the program with all values I entered. The problem I am having is in my cutsomerID it is print out -1 in the output from by -1 ending the loop. When I want it to output 101, 101 (the values I entered). Any help is appreciated.

```
        //Get next customer id
         System.out.println("Enter Customer ID: ");
         customerID = input.nextInt();

}

// Print out table of data and end program
```

Comment: I didn't get what you need - can you provide all your input and what you expect to happen? If it's just putting break - the answer is below, if it's other thing could you be more exact?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `input.nextInt()` in a temporary variable before assigning it to `customerId`:

```
while(true) {
  System.out.println("Enter Customer ID: ");
  int temp = input.nextInt();

  if(temp == -1) {
    break;
  }

  customerId = temp;

// ... rest of code

} // end while
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following near the end of the while

`System.out.println("Enter Customer ID: ");
    int testiId = input.nextInt()
    if(testiId == -1) {
       break;
    }else{
       customerId = testiId;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who responded, and helped. I really appreciate it! I just had brackets in the wrong spot, a simple mistake which I am sure will occur again since I am new to java. Thanks again!